# template view to display an interface

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I have an example of how to use a template view to display an interface have properties ID and Name

Comment: Please provide some more detail and an any example code you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SomeView.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IMyInterface>" %>

ID: <%= Html.Encode(Model.Id) %>
Name <%= Html.Encode(Model.Name) %>
```

IMyInterface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There you go. Hope that helps!